# Mapping function over a list

Tags: function-construction

I am relatively new to mathematica. I got a solution list from my supervisor and now I need to use the values as input for a function. How can I tackle this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Try "Mapping" in Mathematica help browser.

Comment: The `Map[]` function, also known as `/@`, is good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to answer your question in Mathematica...

```
list = Table[i, {i, 1, 5}];
f[x_] := x + 1;
```

First way (prefered) :

```
Map[f, list]
```

Alternatively :

```
Table[f[list[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```

Both give `{2,3,4,5,6}`